# Copy columns of a data frame based on the value of a third column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame with 4 columns. On one of the columns I added a date so that each value looks like this

```
>print(result[[4]][[10000]])
[[10000]]
[1] "Jan"  "14"   "2012"
```

That means that on the 1000'th field of the 4th column I have these 3 fields. This is the only column that is multiple.

Now the other 3 columns of the data frame result are single values not multiple. One of those columns, the first one, has the states of the United States as values. What I want to do is create a new data frame from column 2 and 4 (the one described above) of the result data frame but depending on the state.

So for example I want all the 2nd column and 4th column data of the state of Alabama. I tried this but I don't think it is working properly. "levels" is the 2nd column and "weeks" is the 4th column of the data frame result.

```
rst <- subset(result, result$states == 'Alabama', select = c(result$levels, result$weeks))
```

The problem here is that subset is copying all the columns to rst and not just the second and fourth ones of the result data frame that are linked to Alabama state which are the only ones I want. Any idea how to do this correctly?

*Edit to add the code*

I'm adding the code here since I think there must be something I'm not seeing here. First a small sample of the original data which is on a csv file

```
st      URL                         WEBSITE                 al      aln     wk          WEEKSEASON
Alabama http://adph.org/influenza/  Influenza Surveillance  Level 1 Minimal Oct-04-2008 40  2008-09
Alabama http://adph.org/influenza/  Influenza Surveillance  Level 1 Minimal Oct-11-2008 41  2008-09
Alaska  http://adph.org/influenza/  Influenza Surveillance  Level 1 Minimal Oct-18-2008 42  2008-09
Alaska  http://adph.org/influenza/  Influenza Surveillance  Level 1 Minimal Oct-25-2008 43  2008-09
```

And this is the code

```
#Extracts relevant data from the csv file
extract_data<-function(){

  #open the file. NAME SHOULD BE CHANGED
  sd <- read.csv(file="sdr.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")

  #Extracts the data from the ACTIVITY LEVEL column. Notice that the name of the column was changed on the file
  #to 'al' to make the reference easier
  lv_list <- sd$al
  #Gets only the number from each value getting rid of the word "Level"
  lvs <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(lv_list), " "), function(x) x[2])

  #Gets the ACTIVITY LEVEL NAME. Column name was changed to 'aln' on the file
  lvn_list <- sd$aln

  #Gets the state. Column name was changed to 'st' on the file
  st_list <- sd$st

  #Gets the week. Column name was changed to 'wk' on the file
  wk_list <- sd$wk
  #Divides the weeks data in month, day, year
  wks <- strsplit(as.character(wk_list), "-")

  result<-list("states"=st_list,"levels"=lvs,"lvlnames"=lvn_list,"weeks"=wks)

  return(result)

}

forecast<-function(){

  result=extract_data()

  rst <- subset(result, states == 'Alabama', select = c(levels, weeks))

  return(0) #return results
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there, but you don't need to reference the dataframe in the `select` argument - this should work:

```
rst <- subset(result, states == 'Alabama', select = c(levels, weeks))
```

You could also look into the package `dplyr`, which gives you SQL like abilities and is great for manipulating larger and more complicated data sets.

**EDIT**

Thanks for posting your code - I think I've identified a few problems.

1. The result you return from `extract_data()` is a `list`, not a `data.frame` - which is why the code in `forecast()` doesn't work. If it did return a dataframe the original solution would work.
2. You're forming your list out of a combination of vectors and lists, which is a problem - a `dataframe` is (roughly) a list of `vectors`, not a collection of the two types. If you replace your list creation line with `result <- data.frame(...)` you run into problems because of this.

There are two problematic columns - `lvs` (or `levels`) and `wks` (`weeks`). Where you use `lapply()`, using `sapply()` instead would give you a vector, as required (see [the manual](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html)). The second issue is the weeks column. What you're actually dealing with here is a list of character vectors of length 3. There's no easy way to do what you want - you can't, for example, have each 'cell' of a column in a dataframe contain a character vector, as the columns are themselves vectors.

My suggestions would be to either:

- Use the original format "Oct-01-2008", i.e. construct your data.frame with `wk_list` rather than splitting each date into the three strings;
- Convert the original format into a better time format with a package like [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) (A+++++ would recommend, great package);
- Or finally, split the week column into three columns, so you'd have one for month, one for day and one for year. You could do this very simply from `wk_list` like this:

  ```
  wks <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(wk_list), "-"), function(x) c(x[1], x[2], x[3]))
  Month <- wks[1,]
  Day <- wks[2,]
  Year <- wks[3,]
  ```

Once both `lvs` and `wks` are in vector form, you're good to just run

```
result<-data.frame("states"=st_list,"levels"=lvs,"lvlnames"=lvn_list,"weeks"=wks)
```

and the script should work.

Comment: I tried that but I'm still getting the same result. When I print the first column of rst like this print(rst[[1]]), I'm getting the column with all the states. But that column shouldn't be in rst.

Comment: I ran into some problems with this suggestion. If I split wks like you suggest then the subset call on the forecast function complains that "weeks" doesn't exist. But I took your suggestion and let the date data as it was originally and changed lapply to sapply and it worked! So thanks! :)

Comment: No problem! Yeah you would have to adjust the subset call to select three columns for the date rather than just the one, but leaving the date as is is probably the most straightforward solution!